# Referencing Javascript Object's child from another child's child using a generic pointer

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Please check the following Object Structure:

```
var obj_parent = {
    obj_child : {
        obj_child_var : 15,
        fnc : function() {
            let self = this;
            alert('Called : obj_parent>fnc() | obj_child_var : '+self.obj_child_var);
            obj_parent.obj_fnc();
        }
    },
    obj_fnc : function() {
        alert('Called : obj_parent>obj_fnc();');
    }
};

$(function() {
    obj_parent.obj_child.fnc();
});
```

[Test code at Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tvr55555/pen/GXWPBB) , just click the 'Click Here' button for testing.

At line#7, obj_parent.obj_child.fnc() is calling function obj_parent.obj_fnc() which is from it's parent's parent.

If it was not parent's parent, I could use 'this' to access(like 'obj_child_var' was accessed in lines #5,#6) the function.

Problem here is, if I have to rename 'obj_parent', I will have to rename it everywhere inside it.

What will be the best way to restructure the code where any child or more childs inside them can access any other child from the top root of the object without using it's direct name('obj_parent') but more of a generic way.

like: let self_root = pointer to the 'obj_parent';
And use this self_root instead of 'obj_parent' inside every level, everywhere inside 'obj_parent';

Here I want to keep the entire code compact inside: obj_parent = {..Everything..}

And don't want to put any code of 'obj_parent' outside of it, like using:

obj_parent.prototype.* * * = * * *;

Is there any suggestions on the best way to achieve this by restructuring the codes only inside obj_parent= {...}?

In short I am looking for something like the following inside obj_parent.obj_child.fnc():

```
...
fnc : function() {
  let root_obj_pointer = this.parent;// Points to 'obj_parent';
  root_obj_pointer.obj_fnc();// Instead of obj_parent.obj_fnc();
}
...
```

So that I do not have to rename the 'obj_parent' in obj_parent.obj_fnc(); if the root 'obj_parent' ever gets renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem here is, if I have to rename 'obj_parent', I will have to rename it everywhere inside it.

I would use an IIFE instead, so that you can give the object whatever name you want inside the IIFE's scope, and return the object - then, you can rename the outer variable name from `obj_parent` to whatever you want without problems:

```js
const parentVariableName = (() => {
  const obj_parent = {
    obj_child : {
      obj_child_var : 15,
      fnc : function() {
        let self = this;
        alert('Called : obj_parent>fnc() | obj_child_var : '+self.obj_child_var);
        obj_parent.obj_fnc();
      }
    },
    obj_fnc : function() {
      alert('Called : obj_parent>obj_fnc();');
    }
  };
  return obj_parent;
})();


parentVariableName.obj_child.fnc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage, you can rewrite your child function to an arrow function so the scope is the external context.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZyPmz?editors=0010

```
var parent = {
  child: {
    x: 15,
    fnc: () => {
      let y = parent.child.x
      alert('child.fnc(): ' + y)
      parent.fnc(y)
    }
  },
  fnc: function(y) {
    alert('parent.fnc(): ' + y)
  }
};

function btn_clicked() {
  parent.child.fnc()
}
```